# What's wrong with this block formating code?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void) vPerformBlockOnAllAutoCompleteHandler:((^)(BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler * acHandler))block
{
    for (BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler * acHandler in [self arBGKeywordAutoCompleteHandlers]) {
        block(acHandler);
    }
}
```

Okay, so block is a block that takes BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler as argument. I went through the loop and call block(acHandler).

What's wrong?

The error is:
/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/BGSearchController3.m:218:49: Expected a type. It seems to me I have to add void before the block.

So this works

```
-(void) vPerformBlockOnAllAutoCompleteHandler1:(void (^)(BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler * acHandler))block
{
    for (BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler * acHandler in [self arBGKeywordAutoCompleteHandlers]) {
        block(acHandler);
    }
}
```

However I do not need to add that void if the block does not requires parameter. I found this very strange.

Comment: Who says anything is wrong with it?  The compiler?  If so tell us what it's moaning about.

Comment: Yeah, post the error. Also, what is BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler? Show us that `typedef`. If it's a block, you probably don't want the `*` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
- (void)vPerformBlockOnAllAutoCompleteHandler:(void(^)(BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler*))block
{
 for (BGMotherofAutoCompleteHandler * at in [self arBGKeywordAutoCompleteHandlers]) {
  block(at);
 }
}
```

[Here's a cheat sheet.](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com)

Comment: Interesting. I got to add void if the block contains parameter but I do not need too if the block does not require parameters.